# Is storing multiple singeletion objects in a readonly static dictionary thread safe?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dictionary, static, thread-safety

My question here is this code thread safe? 
I'm trying to cache the `XmlSerializer` object in a local `dictionary` object so it can be reused when required to avoid memory leaks. As XmlSerializer loads the assembly in memory and never unloads.

There will be four possible XmlSerializer objects in the dictionary. You may say create all four XmlSerializer (with different set of constructors) objects in the static constructor and use when required. So that way it would be a thread safe, as we can guarantee that static constructor runs only once. But what if no one uses the xmlserializer feature of the application. Then memory those objects consumed would be wasted.

I can create thread safe singleton objects. But I'm more interested in the context of XmlSerializer. 
I have gone through a lot of posts about Thread Safety and locking. Like this (http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) article tells in more detail but didn't find in particular with XmlSerialization.

So any idea would be highly appreciated!

```
public class SerializeableEntity
{

private readonly static Dictionary<string, XmlSerializer> serializerCache = new Dictionary<string, XmlSerializer>();

public string SerializeIntoXml(SerializeableEntity ObjToSerialize,xmlAttributeOverrides omitProperties,string key)
{
   XmlSerializer serializer=GetSerializerObj(key, ObjToSerialize.GetType(), omitProperties);
//... rest of the logic

}


    private XmlSerializer GetSerializerObj(string key, Type type, XmlAttributeOverrides xmlAttributeOverrides)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = null;
        serializerCache.TryGetValue(key, out serializer);
        if (serializer == null)
        {
            serializer = xmlAttributeOverrides != null ? new XmlSerializer(type, xmlAttributeOverrides) : new XmlSerializer(type);
            serializerCache.Add(key, serializer);
        }
        return serializer;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not thread safe - for instance two threads might run `TryGetValue` at the same time which with return `false` for both. Someone ran into the same issue as you btw: http://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20110612-XmlSerializerConstructorPerformanceIssues.html ?

Comment: Will this `serializers.GetOrAdd(type, t => { return new XmlSerializer(t, new XmlRootAttribute("Value")); });` internally make sure singleton and thread safe?